# Different handling of composer update

Tags: composer-php

Me and my team are working on a project that uses Composer for dependency management. There seems to be a difference in how a `composer update` is handled on several machines (running the same latest build version of Composer), but we can't figure out why.

When my teammate runs a `composer update` on a dependency it tries to remove a lot of data/nodes from the `composer.lock` file (like the entire `dist` and `support` nodes):

[image]

When I run the same update, it tries to re-add all those keys again:

[image]

We can't figure out why this is happening. Is this a certain setting?

**Update:** On further inspection, it appears that the "(dis)appearing" nodes all contain https links, could it have something to do with a (missing) SSL library or something?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of composer? Try `composer selfupdate`. Also, try deleting the composer cache in your home dir (~/.composer)

Comment: @Oli Yes, we're both running the latest build of composer. And I don't seem to have a composer cache dir in my homedir (ls ~/.composer returns "No such file or directory").

Comment: I guess you ran Composer and downloaded released ZIP files, and your coworker cloned the repositories instead. Composer tries to stick with what method has been used previously, so once you cloned the repo, all installs after that will be faster by pulling and checking out the new version, instead of deleting it and downloading a full ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that one Composer prefers `dist` and one prefers `source`.

Look into `~/.composer/config.json` if you defined a preferred install in any of your two composers. Or if you defined different preferred installs in the composer.json.

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

You can force composer to use either `dist` or `source` with

```
composer update --prefer-dist
```

or

```
composer update --prefer-source
```

> **--prefer-source:** There are two ways of downloading a package: `source` and `dist`. For stable versions composer will use the `dist` by default. The source is a version control repository. If `--prefer-source` is enabled, composer will install from source if there is one. This is useful if you want to make a bugfix to a project and get a local git clone of the dependency directly.
>
> **--prefer-dist:** Reverse of `--prefer-source`, composer will install from `dist` if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of the vendors. It is also a way to circumvent problems with git if you do not have a proper setup.

Comment: Are those stray extra *e*s in `--prefere-dist` and `--prefere-source`?